# Streaming Video Often Not Playing On Windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8, video, graphics-card, video-streaming

I'm having an issue that started happening a few days ago. On my MSI GE70 2OE laptop, streaming video has been giving me some issues. It's been mostly hit/miss with whether Netflix or Youtube will play. This is in both the web version, and the metro app. Sometimes it'll randomly be fixed temporarily by something odd, and sometimes it wont. I've had a few instances where letting the video buffer in one browser, then opening it in another browser will get the original to start playing, as will the first one. Often, when the issues with starting playback occur, the browser or application will crash. I'm unsure, but I think I've also seen my network connection hang during the application being unresponsive. I've got 100mbps download, so, my connection *shouldn't* be the issue, but at this point, I'm willing to accept anything as a potential fix.

At one point updating/rolling back my video drivers had fixed the issue, however, it was only temporary, and no longer helps. I've got 2 display adapters. Intel HD Graphics 4600, and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 765M. The Intel graphics should be responsible for handling my video.

Currently the Intel driver version is 10.18.10.3621

As much as I'm biased against it being an issue with my internet, I've had a separate issue with my Ethernet. Around the same time these issues started (give or take a day) my ISP claimed they were having some outages in my area. I had called them due to my internet going off randomly at midnight as the date changed to my bill's due date, assuming they shut my service off. After they had fixed this issue, I found that the Ethernet on my laptop was no longer working properly, and I had to use WiFi. If I reboot the laptop, the Ethernet will work fine for about 10-15 minutes, then stop working, and show a lack of an internet connection. Everyone else in the house is able to use Ethernet though, and I have a direct connection to the router.

If anyone is willing to help me troubleshoot this, I'd be extremely grateful.

EDIT: I've already tried disabling hardware acceleration for Flash. Re-installing flash has also been another weird hit/miss temporary fix, however, it isn't fixing it anymore. In addition, flash is what has been causing the browsers to crash.

Problem is still persisting, and I'm still looking for a possible cause.

Comment: Can the problem be related to specific types of video players (e.g. Flash vs html5 vs silverlight)?

Comment: Youtube is supposed to be using HTML5, and has displayed as using the HTML5 player, however, Netflix is supposed to be using Silverlight. I know Youtube also often uses flash, which has caused the entire browser to crash a few times, mostly when I try working with FireFox.

Comment: Reinstalling flash has also caused a video to start playing before, but it doesn't always. This is with Youtube.

Comment: I would ask a separate question about the Ethernet and link to it here.

Comment: The Ethernet was mentioned in case it were to show any relevance, as the issues occurred at the same time. For all I know, it could be caused by packet loss (which it probably isn't), which that could be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

First, It's reasonably easy to troubleshoot an internet connection using speed test sites such as http://www.speedtest.net/ or http://www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/.  Always remember a single speedtest is telling you more about current internet/local network conditions than it is about the overall health of your connection.  Multiple speedtests from multiple providers etc give a more accurate picture.  It's very possible, especially with a cable connection, to not be getting the class of connection that you are paying for.

Since you have already re-installed flash that eliminates my second suggestion.

Third, if this problem is only existing on one computer on the network, I would check the hardware compression setting for flash.  Right click any flash player and then pick "settings".  The first tab for "Display" will most likely have a single checkbox for "Enable hardware compression" and it is often checked/enabled by default.  Uncheck and test again.

Comment: My speeds are at where they're supposed to be. When the Ethernet is working, I'm getting my full 100mbps down, and when I'm on WiFi, I max out at 60mbps. Both of which are more than adequate for streaming video. I've also disabled hardware acceleration, which I believe is what you're referring to. Same issues.